# Stokes theorem for a current

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, distribution-theory, harmonic-analysis, stokes-theorem

I am struggling to understand the Stokes theorem for currents(differential form with distributional coefficients). The statement is as follows:

Lest $S$ be a current of degree $N - 1$ with compact support in $\Omega$. Then $\int_{\Omega} dS = 0$. The proof is: Let $\chi$ be a smooth cut-off function in $\Omega$ such that $\chi \equiv  1$ in a neighborhood of $K$, a compact subset of $\Omega$ containing the support of $S$. Then $\int_{\Omega} dS = \int_{\Omega} \chi dS = \langle S, d\chi \rangle = 0$.

I am not really following the logic here. First of all, how would one define the integral of a current? I know that a current of degree $p$ is a continuous linear functional on the space of smooth (n-p) forms with compact support, and they are essentially forms with distributional coefficients. My guess is that the coefficients of a top degree form will always be locally integrable, then you just integrate the coefficients over the support of the current but I am not sure whether this is the correct interpretation or not.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but if your manifold is simply a vector space it looks easy to construct currents that aren't locally $L^1$. To define the integral of a current of top degree, since it's a differential form of top degree with distributional coefficients, this integral should be a distribution. So define $\langle\int{j},\,f\rangle = \int_{j(f)}$ where $j(f)$ is (check it in charts) a smooth $n$-form. So when the current at $x$ is some $h(x,y)\omega_x$ where $h(x,y)$ is a locally $L^1$ density in $y$, I'd say that its integral is $f \longmapsto \int_x{\omega_x \cdot \int_y{h(x,y)f(y)}}$.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. So the integral should be a current according to your definition. Then how does one justify the proof of the stokes theorem.  I mean from the equality $\int_{\Omega} \chi dS = \langle S, d \chi \rangle $, it seems to be suggesting that the integral is a number because $\langle S, d \chi \rangle$ is just a number.

Comment: Good point – it got me thinking. For instance, the Fourier transform of a compactly supported distribution in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a function (and thus its “integral” is a number). I think the integral can only be defined as a distribution in general (ie a map smooth functions -> scalars), but for a compactly supported current, it also has a numeric version, such that, for each current $S$ and each smooth $f$, the numeric integral of $fS$ is $\langle S,\, f\rangle$. And the integral which we prove is zero is the “numeric” integral rather than the “distributional” integral.

Comment: You might get better answers if you add the tag "geometric measure theory."  (Probably the "harmonic analysis" tag is not helping here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the statement is a tautology but at the same time abuses the notation. $S$ is of degree $N-1$ (in view of the statement the dimension must be $N$) so it 'acts' upon 1 forms (with smooth and compact coefficients). The exterior derivative is defined by duality so $dS$ acts upon $0$-forms, i.e. functions. So the stated claim may be written:

$$ "\langle dS,1 \rangle" = \langle dS, \chi \rangle 
= (-1)^N \langle S, d\chi \rangle = 0 $$
since $d\chi$ has support disjoint from that of $S$.
You may look e.g. in chapter 3 of
[Currents](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Etien-cuong.dinh/Cours2005/Master/cours.pdf) for this type of calculations. I have put the first expression in quotation marks as it is also a slight abuse of notation  since the constant function 1 does not have compact support, but it still makes sense since $S$ is supposed to have compact support.

The above coincides with standard integrals when these are defined but the notation may be misleading.

Some more details: In $n$ dimensional Euclidean space and for (non-negative)
$p+q=n$ there is a
natural bi-linear map on smooth forms $(\alpha,\beta) \in \Omega^p({\Bbb R}^n) \times \Omega^q({\Bbb R}^n)) \rightarrow \int \alpha\wedge \beta\in {\Bbb R}$ defined when at least one of the forms (say $\beta$) has compact support.
The map, $\beta\in \Omega^q_c({\Bbb R}^n) \mapsto \langle \Lambda_\alpha, \beta\rangle =\int \alpha \wedge \beta$ then defines a continuous linear map on the space of $q$-forms with compact support (equipped with its natural Frechet space topology). The space of such linear maps is called the space of $p$-currents, which thus contains $\Omega^p({\Bbb R}^n)$ as a naturally embedded image under the map $\alpha \mapsto \Lambda_\alpha$ above.

For smooth forms $\alpha$ and $\beta$ of degree $p$ and $q$, respectively, one has $d(\alpha\wedge \beta)= d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^p \alpha \wedge d\beta$. However, when $p+q=n-1$ then by Stokes,
$\int_D d(\alpha \wedge \beta) = \int_{\partial D} \alpha\wedge \beta = 0$ when the open set $D$ contains the support of $\beta$. Thus,
$$ \langle d\Lambda_\alpha, \beta \rangle = \int d\alpha \wedge \beta = -(-1)^{p} \int \alpha \wedge d\beta = (-1)^{p+1} \langle \Lambda , d\beta\rangle.$$
One then declares equality of extremities to define the exterior derivative of any $p$-current $\Lambda$ (when $p=n-q-1$). This now leads to the tautology as explained above.